# Rearranged soap operation in WSDL after Tomcat deploy

Tags: java, tomcat, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

my case is rather curious: I have a working JAX-WS running on a Tomcat 7.0.21 instance. A new requirement forced me to add soapActions but after the Deployment, my wsdl was rearranged. Well, only if you took at it via URL.

My file contents on the server:

```
<wsdl:operation name="doStuff">
  <wsdl:documentation>...</wsdl:documentation>
  <soap:operation soapAction="doStuff"></soap:operation>
  <wsdl:input message="tns:myRequest" name="myRequest"></wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:myResponse" name="myResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Contents loaded via URL:

```
<wsdl:operation name="doStuff">
  <wsdl:documentation>...</wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:input message="tns:myRequest" name="myRequest"></wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:myResponse" name="myResponse"></wsdl:output>
  <soap:operation soapAction="doStuff"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

It is the correct wsdl in the file because every change I make is visible via URL after a Tomcat restart. Unfortunately due to this rearrangement the wsdl is no longer valid.

Any ideas what could cause such a behaviour?

Best regards, 
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is awkward, it was in the wrong element. I put the soap:operation in the wsdl:portType and not in the wsdl:binding.